# pydoc's locate module does not handle errors properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, pydoc

`pydoc.locate` does not throw an error when called from a block of code or from the basic interactive shell. It's only when I fire up the IPython console from within pycharm does `locate` throw an error if a non existent module is supplied as an argument.

Python code: Prints `None` as output

```
import pydoc


def test_pydoc_locate():
    print pydoc.locate('nonexistent.module.name')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_pydoc_locate()
```

Running IPython from pycharm

```
from pydoc import locate
imported_module = locate('nonexistent.module.name')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/testuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3035, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-3-756f8a48c1ad>", line 1, in <module>
    imported_module = locate('nonexistent.module.name')
  File "/home/testuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pydoc.py", line 1517, in locate
    nextmodule = safeimport(join(parts[:n+1], '.'), forceload)
  File "/home/testuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pydoc.py", line 342, in safeimport
    raise ErrorDuringImport(path, sys.exc_info())
ErrorDuringImport: problem in nonexistent - <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named nonexistent
```

Running python from the terminal

```
>>> from pydoc import locate
>>> imported_module = locate('nonexistent.module.name')
>>> print imported_module
None
```

Is there something that the pycharm IDE sets as system variables that enables `locate` to realize that there is an import error?

I would highly appreciate it if someone could test and explain this behavior.

Thanks!