# ModelForm has no model class specified.[django]

Tags: python, django, authentication

In my **forms** i have:

```
from pydoc import locate

from django import forms
from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UsernameField
from django.core.validators import EmailValidator

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = UsernameField(label=_("Username"), widget=forms.TextInput(), )
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, label="Email", widget=forms.EmailInput(), validators=[EmailValidator])

    class Meta:
        model = locate(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)   <--- HERE
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")
```

in **user app** in **models**:

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

In my **project settings.py** I set up

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.Profile'
```

And it gives me

```
ValueError at /user/register 
ModelForm has no model class specified.
```

When I change class Meta **in** my **form** to:

```
class Meta:

        model = Profile   <--- HERE
```

Everything is OK. Why my *model = locate(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)* doesnt work?

Comment: What does locate do?

Comment: Perhaps `locate` method does not return a model class?

Comment: locate should go to settings and takes this fromthere:
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.Profile'

Comment: @AM0k: the problem is that `'user.Profile'` is not a valid qualfied name. That should have been `user.models.Profile` (but you can not use that, since Django works with a slightly different naming system). You can make use of `apps.get_model(..)` but for the user model, you can make use of `get_user_model()` directly).

Comment: Thank You very much... I have solution where it is 
exactly same like my. There is ok, my doestn work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`get_user_model()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model) to get a reference to the model that you specified as `AUTH_USER_MODEL`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = UsernameField(
        label=_('Username'),
        widget=forms.TextInput()
    )
    email = forms.EmailField(
        max_length=254,
        label='Email',
        widget=forms.EmailInput(),
        validators=[EmailValidator]
    )

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('username', 'email')
```

`locate` will not work in this case, since it [returns `None` in case the module is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37787819/67579), it thus "fails silently". The location of the `Profile` class is `user.models.Profile`, Django only has some special syntax `app_name.ModelName` it uses to refer to a model.

For another model, you can make use of the [**`apps.get_model(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model):

```
from django.apps import apps
from django import forms

# name of the model
model_name = 'app_name.ModelName'

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = apps.get_model(model_name)
        fields = '__all__'
```